# Why in JIRA my field Resolution is labeled as Unresolved, when status is Resolved?

Tags: agile, kanban, jira, project-management-style

Question is pretty simple, I've a Kanban project, with a personal workflow that provides different statuses, as Resolved.
When I drag and drop to this last one through the lanes, or when I set it manually to Resolved status, the Resolution fields is still Unresolved, and one of my widget - *Created VS Resolved chart* - is not working properly.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JIRA, an issue is only considered resolved if it has a value in the RESOLUTION field.

The status of the issue doesn't actually matter. For example, it could have a status of RESOLVED or CLOSED but would still be considered as unresolved by JIRA if the RESOLUTION field was empty.

So, the trick to resolving issues is to ensure that you have setup your workflow correctly. Make sure that the final [transition](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/working-with-workflows-802592661.html) in your workflow includes the *resolve issue screen*.

This screen is where you set the RESOLUTION. For example, you might have a RESOLUTION of "done", "duplicate", "won't fix", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging from the DONE lane to the RESOLVED let you chose from options RESOLVE or RESOLVE ISSUE. RESOLVE ISSUE is the option to chose for having the label Resolution in place.